# Select multiple <option> keeping track of selected elements

Tags: jquery, tags

I get the feeling I'm on the wrong track after several days here.
Trying to use a `<select>` to keep track of multiple client choices.

```
<div id="ajax">
<select id="select_site" name="site" multiple>
    <option value="" selected>checked</option>
    <option value="" selected>checked</option>
    <option value="">unchecked</option>
    <option value="">unchecked</option>
</select>
<button id="continue" type="button">Save</button>
</div>
```

desired result:
click checked alert('subtract from checked')
click unchecked alert('add to checked')

```
$('#ajax').on('click', '#select_site option', function () {
  var checked = $('#select_site option:selected');
  if ($(this).prop('selected') == 'selected') {
    alert('subtract from checked');
  } else {
    alert('add to checked');
  }
  $('#select_site').empty();
  $.each(checked, function (i, v) {
    $('#select_site').append(v);
  });
  });  

$('#ajax').on('click', '#continue', function () {
  var checked = $('#select_site option:selected');
  alert(checked);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/struggle/akshC/)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your script.

1: It will not be on mouse click, but on `mousedown` so you can preevnt default behavior.

2: As i said, you need to prevent default behavior, so you nned this :

```
pseudo-on(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    //Your code
})
```

3: Using `.prop()` return a boolean, so at the moment, your condition is always false. Your condition can simply be `if ($(this).prop('selected'))`

4: Since the default behavior is prevented, you need to manually add or delete a selected option.

5: Because you manually select options, the `var checked` must be declared.

6: I don't know what you meant to do with the `.each()` loop with the append, but i don't think you'll need it with my solution. The `var checked` will aswell be useless in this case.

Here a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/akshC/1/

Comment: Appreciate your response. I had already tried 1,2, & 4. Went to your fiddle using firefox v21.0 and it DID-NOT work. Using safari 5.1.7 it DID work. So I'm wondering `compadabily` issues? Where do I even start? (Thought jQuery takes care of this). Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, tried to google a little bit, cant find anything, sorry :/